# Magento2 Export Button (CSv) in custom grid

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

How to add CSV export button in Custom grid in magento2.  I have created a grid and form. Need to add csv export function in magento2.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We need to know what you've tried.

Answer (score 3):

create your controller

```
<?php
namespace Yourpackage\Yourmodule\Controller\Adminhtml\Sample;

class ExportCsv extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
  protected $_fileFactory;
  protected $_response;
  protected $_view;
  protected $directory;
  protected $converter;
  protected $resultPageFactory ;
  protected $directory_list;
  public function __construct( \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context  $context,
         \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
        ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory  = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
}
 public function execute()
 {
    $fileName = 'yourfilename.csv';
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory ->create();
    $content = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('yourblockname')->getCsv();;
    $this->_sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content);

 }

protected function _sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content, $contentType='application/octet-stream') {

     $this->_response->setHttpResponseCode(200)
        ->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true)
        ->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true)
        ->setHeader('Content-type', $contentType, true)
        ->setHeader('Content-Length', strlen($content), true)
        ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"', true)
        ->setHeader('Last-Modified', date('r'), true)
        ->setBody($content)
        ->sendResponse();
    die;

 }
}
```

create your layout xml
yourmodule_yourcontroller_exportcsv

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="yourmodule_yourcontroller_grid"/>
</page>
```

Comment: While we open such such csv file, it is asking for 'Filter selection' why so it asking please ?

Comment: Because for first time you open that file it ask you to separate the column on which basis like comma(,) or semi-column(;) etc.

Comment: @KhoduVaishnav, this export the csv file to root folder, can we export it into the pub/media folder? how that can be done?

Answer (score 3):

Below Is a Default Class it only Export that Data which are show in your Admin Grid not Export your whole data

FIND in your grid column,

and add only this code in ui contactus_grid.xml or any other.

```
<exportButton class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/export" displayArea="dataGridActions">
    <settings>
        <options>
            <option name="csv" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">csv</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">mui/export/gridToCsv</item>
            </option>
            <option name="xml" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">xml</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Excel XML</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">mui/export/gridToXml</item>
            </option>
        </options>
    </settings>
</exportButton>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I couldn't found complete answers. Here is how you should proceed so you can filter data from admin grid.

Pls remove unwanted lines from execute method. I was in the middle of working on this code when I so this question

First create your UI Component

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <exportButton class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/export" displayArea="dataGridActions">
            <settings>
                <options>
                    <option name="cvs" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="string">csv</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">controller/results/export</item>
                    </option>
                    <option name="xml" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="string">xml</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Excel XML</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">skininc/results/export</item>
                    </option>
                </options>
            </settings>
        </exportButton>
</listingToolbar>
```

Next create your controller for skininc/results/export

```
<?php
/**
 * @category Magento 2 Module
 * @package  Theiconnz\Frontendflow
 * @author   Don Nuwinda
 */
namespace MyModule\Frontendflow\Controller\Adminhtml\Results;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory;
use MyModule\Frontendflow\Model\ResourceModel\MyData\CollectionFactory;

class Export extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\ForwardFactory
     */
    protected $resultForwardFactory;

    /**
     * Massactions filter
     *
     * @var Filter
     */
    protected $filter;

    /**
     * @var MetadataProvider
     */
    protected $metadataProvider;
    /**
     * @var WriteInterface
     */
    protected $directory;
    /**
     * @var ConvertToCsv
     */
    protected $converter;
    /**
     * @var FileFactory
     */
    protected $fileFactory;



    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
        Filter $filter,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        ConvertToCsv $converter,
        FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider $metadataProvider,
        \MyModule\Frontendflow\Model\ResourceModel\MyData $resource,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
        ) {
            $this->resources = $resource;
            $this->filter = $filter;
            $this->_connection = $this->resources->getConnection();
            $this->directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
            $this->metadataProvider = $metadataProvider;
            $this->converter = $converter;
            $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
            $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * export.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Forward
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());

        $component = $this->filter->getComponent();
        $this->filter->prepareComponent($component);
        $dataProvider = $component->getContext()->getDataProvider();
        $dataProvider->setLimit(0, false);
        $ids = [];

        foreach ($collection as $document) {
            $ids[] = (int)$document->getId();
        }

        $searchResult = $component->getContext()->getDataProvider()->getSearchResult();
        $fields = $this->metadataProvider->getFields($component);
        $options = $this->metadataProvider->getOptions();
        $name = md5(microtime());
        $file = 'export/'. $component->getName() . $name . '.csv';
        $this->directory->create('export');
        $stream = $this->directory->openFile($file, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();
        $stream->writeCsv($this->metadataProvider->getHeaders($component));
        foreach ($searchResult->getItems() as $document) {
            if( in_array( $document->getId(), $ids ) ) {
                $this->metadataProvider->convertDate($document, $component->getName());
                $stream->writeCsv($this->metadataProvider->getRowData($document, $fields, $options));
            }
        }
        $stream->unlock();
        $stream->close();
        return $this->fileFactory->create('export.csv', [
            'type' => 'filename',
            'value' => $file,
            'rm' => true  // can delete file after use
        ], 'var');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just by adding this line under listingToolbar opening tag did the trick for me

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
 <exportButton name="export_button"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

To Do Export in grid using UI Components in magento2

Under Container tag add following lines in ui listing component xml

```
  <exportButton name="export_button">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">vendor_listing.vendor_listing.example_blog_columns.ids</item>
        </item>
      </argument>
     </exportButton>
```

This will generate csv for loaded collection in grid in magento2

Answer (score 1):

create your controller

```
<?php
namespace Yourpackage\Yourmodule\Controller\Adminhtml\Report;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class ExportCsv extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {

protected $resultPageFactory;
protected $fileFactory;

/**
 * 
 * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,    
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->fileFactory       = $fileFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * 
 * @return type
 */
public function execute() {
    $fileName = 'salesreport.csv';

    $content = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock(
                    \Ktpl\RepresentativeReport\Block\Adminhtml\Salesdata\Grid::class
            )->getCsvFile();

    return $this->fileFactory->create($fileName, $content, DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
 }
}
```

Comment: Add some explantion. This is obvious your code has no closing bracket, this may be incomplete or wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**Below Is a Default Class it only Export that Data which are show in your Admin Grid not Export your whole data**

```
<exportButton class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton">
```

If you  want all Data you have create a Custom Export  Button that export your all data.

edit in your Ui-Component file where  Admin Grid Show

**[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \view\adminhtml\ui_component**

Add this code to add Button into Admin Grid

***Ui-ComponentFIleName.xml***

```
<item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">

    <item name="import" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="name" xsi:type="string">import</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Import</item>
        <item name="class" xsi:type="string">secondary</item>
        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/importdata</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
    </item>

    <item name="export" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="name" xsi:type="string">export</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Export</item>
        <item name="class" xsi:type="string">secondary</item>
        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportdata</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
    </item>

</item>
```

**Now create a File that Export or Import Data. File Name must be same as you define in Ui-Component file**

```
  <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportdata</item>

  <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/importdata</item>
```

File path must be like this

**[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \ Controller \ Adminhtml \ [Controller_name] \ Exportdata.php**

***Exportdata.php***

```
<?php

namespace [vendor_name]\[module_name]\Controller\Adminhtml\[Controller_name];

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;


class Exportdata extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $uploaderFactory;

    protected $_locationFactory; 

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \[vendor_name]\[module_name]\Model\locatorFactory $locationFactory // This is returns Collaction of Data

    ) {
       parent::__construct($context);
       $this->_fileFactory = $fileFactory;
       $this->_locationFactory = $locationFactory;
       $this->directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR); // VAR Directory Path
       parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {   
        $name = date('m-d-Y-H-i-s');
        $filepath = 'export/export-data-' .$name. '.csv'; // at Directory path Create a Folder Export and FIle
        $this->directory->create('export');

        $stream = $this->directory->openFile($filepath, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();

        //column name dispay in your CSV 

        $columns = ['Col-1-name','Col-2-name','Col-3-name','Col-4-name','Col-5-name','Col-6-name','Col-7-name','Col-8-name','Col-9-name',];

            foreach ($columns as $column) 
            {
                $header[] = $column; //storecolumn in Header array
            }

        $stream->writeCsv($header);

        $location = $this->_locationFactory->create();
        $location_collection = $location->getCollection(); // get Collection of Table data 

        foreach($location_collection as $item){

            $itemData = [];

            // column name must same as in your Database Table 

            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-1-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-2-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-3-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-4-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-5-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-6-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-7-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-8-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-9-name');

            $stream->writeCsv($itemData);

        }

        $content = [];
        $content['type'] = 'filename'; // must keep filename
        $content['value'] = $filepath;
        $content['rm'] = '1'; //remove csv from var folder

        $csvfilename = 'locator-import-'.$name.'.csv';
        return $this->_fileFactory->create($csvfilename, $content, DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);

    }


}
```

Now you can Click on the Export Button and See your .csv file Downloaded below.

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 0):

Add CSV export button to your grid block layout (XML):

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="your.grid.container">
            <block class="Yourpackage\Yourmodule\Block\Adminhtml\Sample\Grid" name="sample.grid" as="grid">
                <!-- Arguments or blocks -->

                <!-- Export Widget -->
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Export" name="sample.grid.export" as="grid.export">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="exportTypes" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="csv" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportCsv</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>

                <!-- Columns block -->
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create your controller:

```
<?php
namespace Yourpackage\Yourmodule\Controller\Adminhtml\Sample;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class ExportCsv extends \Yourpackage\Yourmodule\Controller\Adminhtml\Sample
{
    /**
     * Export data grid to CSV format
     *
     * @return ResponseInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $fileName = 'sample_data.csv';
        $content = $this->_view->getLayout()->getChildBlock('sample.grid', 'grid.export');

        return $this->_fileFactory->create(
            $fileName,
            $content->getCsvFile($fileName),
            DirectoryList::VAR_DIR
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: ,i have tried this and getting empty for print_r($content).not getting the layout blocks.any suggestions

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getCsvFile() on boolean

Comment: Replace `$content` by data from your model and it will work like a charm!